# SQL SELECT query with custom column, then summed and grouped by column

Tags: mysql

Trying to basically do two queries in one and join them:

First query:

```
SELECT y.exchange
      ,  k.close * k.volume money_volume  
 FROM symbols y
JOIN stocks k 
    ON y.id = k.id  
 WHERE k.t = '20160323'  
  ORDER 
    BY money_volume DESC
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT SUM(money_volume) AS money_volume_sum  
  FROM [table just made above]  
 GROUP 
    BY symbols.exchange
```

Thanks for reviewing, and let me know if you have an efficient way to combine these two into one SELECT query.

Cheers.

Comment: Final answer used was:



SELECT SUM(money_volume) AS money_volume_sum,
exchange
FROM (
    SELECT symbols.exchange, stocks.close * stocks.volume AS money_volume  
    FROM symbols  
    JOIN stocks ON symbols.id = stocks.id  
    WHERE stocks.t = '20160323'  
    ORDER BY money_volume DESC  
) t
GROUP BY exchange  
ORDER BY money_volume_sum DESC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(money_volume) AS money_volume_sum  
FROM (
    SELECT symbols.exchange, stocks.close * stocks.volume AS money_volume  
    FROM symbols  
    JOIN stocks ON symbols.id = stocks.id  
    WHERE stocks.t = '20160323'  
    ORDER BY money_volume DESC  
) t
GROUP BY exchange
```

Answer (score 0):

This concept is called a derived table ([see details in the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx)). Essentially, you will simply put your first query in parentheses and place it in the `FROM` clause of your second query:

```
SELECT SUM(money_volume) AS money_volume_sum  
FROM (
  SELECT y.exchange
      ,  k.close * k.volume money_volume  
  FROM symbols y
  JOIN stocks k 
    ON y.id = k.id  
  WHERE k.t = '20160323'
  -- In some databases, including SQL Server, derived tables must not have any ORDER BY
  -- clause, unless accompanied by TOP or OFFSET / FETCH
) t -- You must give this derived table a name
GROUP BY exchange
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a virtual table which makes things very clear. Specially when you end up joining 15+ sub results.

```
WITH CTE as (
SELECT y.exchange
      ,  k.close * k.volume money_volume  
 FROM symbols y
JOIN stocks k 
    ON y.id = k.id  
 WHERE k.t = '20160323'  
  )


SELECT SUM(CTE.money_volume) AS money_volume_sum  
FROM CTE
GROUP BY symbols.exchange  
ORDER BY CTE.money_volume
```