# SUM of complex derived table

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I get the sum of this complex query?

Looking for the sum of money_volume_sum.  (I can be a seperate query so I can use it as a variable to calculate percentages.)

Also: Is there a way to put this in same query?

Based from this original question on stackoverflow:
[SQL SELECT query with custom column, then summed and grouped by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344207/sql-select-query-with-custom-column-then-summed-and-grouped-by-column)

Cheers!

```
    SELECT SUM(money_volume) AS money_volume_sum,
    exchange        
    FROM (
        SELECT k.exchange, y.close * y.volume AS money_volume  
        FROM symbols k
        JOIN stocks y ON k.id = y.id  
        WHERE y.t = '20160323'  
        ORDER BY money_volume DESC  
    ) t
    GROUP BY exchange  
    ORDER BY money_volume_sum DESC
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Sample data and desired results really help.  And why doesn't the original answer (which you accepted) work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the percentage in the outer query, you can use a trick in MySQL of using variables:

```
SELECT exchange, SUM(money_volume) AS money_volume_sum, @s as total_sum
FROM (SELECT k.exchange, y.close * y.volume AS money_volume,
             (@s := @s + y.close * y.volume) as cumesum
      FROM symbols k JOIN
           stocks
           y ON k.id = y.id CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @s := 0) params
      WHERE y.t = '20160323'  
     ) t
GROUP BY exchange  
ORDER BY money_volume_sum DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you nice trick.  I'll try to study it to figure out why it worked lol.